# Will enabling Comcast Business Gateway Port triggering lock me out?

Tags: firewall, router, gateway, outboundrules

Device info:

- SMC Networks
- Firmware 3.1.6.56

I am remotely logged into a server and configuring the "Comcast Business Gateway". At the current moment, Within the Firewall >> Port Configuration >> Port Triggering page, it is currently configured to "Disable all Port Triggering Rules" and has no rules configured.

My question is, if I enable it then does it only open ports for what is on that page? For example, if I just enable it without actually adding Port Triggering Rules then will it boot me off the network or cause any network issues?

I am trying to troubleshoot an appliance device not communicating with a cloud service. All in-bound "Port forwarding" rules are configured, so we want to run some test on outbound traffic utilizing the "port triggering".

Have been trying to find documentation which can answer the above concern, which is what happens if I enable "Port Triggering" rules but have no actual rules configured. I am not sure if once I enable it, that it blocks all outbound traffic on ports which have no have no rules configured.

Comment: Seems like a great question for Comcast support.

Comment: Would be if I had access to the Comcast Account information to contact support.

Comment: Vendor should be your first stop before coming here. We're not internet tech support. Just talk with the account holder and get support info.

Comment: It is a question i figured people would have run into when configuring a comcast gateway as it is a common setting. If I had access to get the account information, I would have. But I do not.